# How to delete custom statistics/dimensions in Apigee?

Tags: analytics, apigee

I've been experimenting with Apigee's [custom statistics](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/statistics-collector-policy) for gathering data about requests coming into the API. Now I have a whole bunch of temporary statistics names that I no longer need, like `bozo`, `bozo1`, `my_test`, etc.

How do I get rid of certain dimensions so they don't show up in the `Custom Dimensions` part of the Drilldowns dropdown?

I tried doing the following DELETE call, but it didn't work:

```
curl -X DELETE https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/o/{org}/environments/test/stats/bozo -u {username}:{password}
```

I don't see anything in the [API Documentation](http://apigee.com/docs/management/apis/get/organizations/%7Borg_name%7D/environments/%7Benv_name%7D/stats/%7Bdimension_name%7D)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get it deleted is if you have the commercial version of Apigee Edge and open a support ticket -- the ops team may be able to get in cleaned out.

This is really important when defining custom stats with generic labels like "Title" -- if you have two stats collectors with different data but the same label, you'll get mixed up data in Analytics and muck up your data.